# Administrator is being blocked by server - error 406?

Tags: php, blocking

Few days ago I put online new portal that comes with cms I made myself. Problem that occurred is following: Administrator logs to cms, publishes few news and then he can't access portal at all (whole domain is not accessible to him). Then he tried to access it via mobile phone and he succeeded... but only for a few minutes, because after publishing few news he couldn't access domain again. This happened few days when portal was launched. Then after hour-two of waiting domain is accessible and then again same problem... I thought it could be some physical problem because it was stormy that night, so I was comforting myself. But problem started repeating the day after and yesterday, when he restarted his router and then immediately the domain became accessible. Again, he published few news and then again he was blocked. Restarting router (to get new ip) resolved the problem temporary. What I don't understand is how comes that I'm not blocked because I tried to do all things he did in CMS but it didn't affect me. Is there possibility that his IP was blocked by server because of some errors I made while programming this CMS. I used "a lot" of jquery (ajax) and php.

When accessing via Firefox this is error (original is in Croatian so I'll try to translate): Litteraly translated, first sentence is this: "Link is broken", but I think software is not translated good and it shoul be probably "Connection could not be established". - This document doesn't contain any data. This page is temporary not available or too busy. Try again in few moments. If you can't load any page please check you network settings. If you computer is protected with firewall or proxy, check if Firefox has permission to access Internet.

He tried using Firefox and Internet Explorer. It was tested on 2 computers that share one connection to internet. Mobile phone uses it's own connection to internet. Server uses Apache 2.2.11 (Unix).

This is from error log I found that concerns his IP address:

```
    [Sat Oct 17 13:29:16 2009] [error] [client 212.15.176.191] File does not exist: /home2/sinjcom/public_html/406.shtml, referer: http://www.sinj.com.hr/administracija/index.php?link=news
    [Sat Oct 17 13:28:38 2009] [error] [client 212.15.176.191] File does not exist: /home2/sinjcom/public_html/406.shtml, referer: http://www.sinj.com.hr/administracija/index.php?link=news
    [Sat Oct 17 13:27:54 2009] [error] [client 212.15.176.191] File does not exist: /home2/sinjcom/public_html/406.shtml, referer: http://www.sinj.com.hr/administracija/index.php?link=news
    [Sat Oct 17 13:27:08 2009] [error] [client 212.15.176.191] File does not exist: /home2/sinjcom/public_html/406.shtml, referer: http://www.sinj.com.hr/administracija/index.php?link=news

    [Sat Oct 17 13:21:56 2009] [error] [client 78.0.153.177] File does not exist: /home2/sinjcom/public_html/406.shtml, referer: http://www.sinj.com.hr/administracija/index.php?link=news
    [Sat Oct 17 13:21:19 2009] [error] [client 78.0.153.177] File does not exist: /home2/sinjcom/public_html/406.shtml, referer: http://www.sinj.com.hr/administracija/index.php?link=news
    [Sat Oct 17 13:20:18 2009] [error] [client 78.0.153.177] File does not exist: /home2/sinjcom/public_html/406.shtml, referer: http://www.sinj.com.hr/administracija/index.php?link=news
    [Sat Oct 17 13:19:21 2009] [error] [client 78.0.153.177] File does not exist: /home2/sinjcom/public_html/406.shtml, referer: http://www.sinj.com.hr/administracija/index.php?link=news
    [Sat Oct 17 13:18:57 2009] [error] [client 78.0.153.177] File does not exist: /home2/sinjcom/public_html/406.shtml, referer: http://www.sinj.com.hr/administracija/index.php?link=news
```

Thanks in advance for answering.

Ile

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED:**

I contacted my hosting provider and they said problem was in mod_sceurity line `<(.|n)+>`
I don't know details but it really solved my problem